# how to parse data from json Array

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I unable to get the **driverId** from this JSON

```
[data: [{"id":"619","driverId":"6789","starting_time":"2016-12-12 23:24:50","end_time":null}]]
```

Here is my full code

```
 //selector Method SESSION_STATUS_REQUEST_COMPLETE
    func afterServiceStatus(notification : NSNotification) {

        print(notification.userInfo!)
        guard let data =  notification.userInfo!["data"]  else{
        print("data have no idea ")
        return
        }

        if let driverId = notification.userInfo![0]!["driverId"] {

            print(driverId)

        }
    //        if let driverId = data["driverId"] as? String{
    //
    //           print(driverId)
    //        }


    }
```

Comment: change your condition to this one if let driverId = data![0]!["driverId"] {

            print(driverId)

        }

Comment: you should take a look at swiftyJSON to get rid of this ' ! ' madness

Comment: @SapanaRanipa force to deleted data after '!' then run time bad  instruction error trowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...

```
func afterServiceStatus(notification : NSNotification) {

            print(notification.userInfo!)
            guard let data =  notification.userInfo!["data"]  else{
                print("data have no idea ")
                return
            }

             let driverId = notification.userInfo![0]?.objectForKey("data")?.valueForKey("driverId") 

                print(driverId)



        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid all the force unwraps, because they make your code vulnerable to crashing if you get back JSON in an unexpected format.

This should retrieve the `driverId` from your dictionary:

```
func afterServiceStatus(notification: NSNotification) {

  guard
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo as? [String: Any],
    let data = userInfo["data"] as? [[String: Any]],
    let driverId = data[0]["driverId"] as? String
  else {
    return
  }

  print(driverId)
}
```

Comment: '[NSObject : AnyObject]?' is not convertible to '[String : Any]'

Comment: Definition conflicts with previous value

Answer (score 0):

```
func afterServiceStatus(notification : NSNotification) {

            print(notification.userInfo!)
            guard let data =  notification.userInfo!["data"]  else{
                print("data have no idea ")
                return
            }
if let driverId = notification.userInfo[0]["data"]["driverId"].string
         {
            print(driverId)
         }
}
```

If it doesn't work then forward me link, I'll give you proper solution.